# Spinners populated from database not registering selection

Tags: android

I'm having a problem implementing spinners and getting them to work the way I want.  I have one spinner containing state abbreviations that is populated from an array.  Depending on the state that the user selects, the application should perform a database query and populate the second spinner with locations of stores in the selected state.

The first spinner works fine, performs the query successfully and populates the second spinner.  I want to get the value from the second spinner and display it in a toast message.  Here is where the problem occurs.  The second spinner is not registering clicks after it is initially filled.

In the example below, the user selects RI from the first spinner.  The second spinner is populated and the first town in the spinner "COVENTRY" is shown in a toast message.  The problem comes in when I try to select other towns from the 2nd spinner...  although the towns are shown in the spinner, they aren't coming up in the toast message.

```
if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("RI")) {
            HDHelper hdtable = new HDHelper(getApplicationContext());
            hdtable.open();
            Cursor c = hdtable.fetchRI();
            if (c != null){
            SimpleCursorAdapter hdadapter1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, // Give the cursor to the list adapter
            new String[] {c.getColumnName(2)}, // Map the column in the HD database to...
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1}); // The view defined in the XML template
            hdadapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            Spinner hdstoresspin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hdstorespinner);
            hdstoresspin.setAdapter(hdadapter1);
            hdstoresspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

            String text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(hdtable.KEY_STORENUMBER));

            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            startManagingCursor(c); 
            hdtable.close();
        }
```

Here is the relevant DBHelper section dealing with the above query:

```
public Cursor fetchRI() {
    String RIquery = "SELECT * FROM HDStores WHERE state = 'RI' ORDER BY storenumber";
    return mDb.rawQuery(RIquery, null);
  }
```

UPDATE:  I actually think the `OnItemSelectedListener`is working properly.  It is registering clicks, but no matter which value I click on, only the first value is reflected in the toast message.  Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it would be something stupid that I missed.  I went back to working on it again after a few days break and it jumped right out at me.  The cursor needed to be finalized as well.